# Draw order sorting in opengl

Tags: opengl, z-order, orthographic

I have an orthographic projection, and I am drawing sprites. The problem is that the sprites appear in the order drawn in OpenGL. I would like to assign a Z value to them, and have them draw in a sorted Z order. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort them and then draw them in that order. There's really no need to go any further than that. Just stick them all in a data structure, sort them, and draw them in that order.

Comment: I figured this would be the way to go, wasn't sure if OpenGL supported it natively.

Comment: @StormKiernan: Well, if your sprites are fully opaque you could have the Z-buffer do the work for you. However sprites usually have transparent regions, so you'll have to sort them. However using a quick or merge sort you'll likely get O(n log(n)) complexity.

Comment: @datenwolf Yeah I just finished implementing the merge sort.

Comment: Hi. Can you help me ? I created the post in stack overflow, before finding this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31091314/opengl-3-does-the-draw-order-affects-objects-position-on-z-axis-images-inc