# Does the draw order affects objects position in depth? (images included)

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, draw

I have a few objects on the scene and even if I specify that the object A have y= 10 (the highest object), from the TOP camera I can see the bottom objects through the object A. Here is an image from my scene.

[image]

And only today I found an interesting property that draw order of models matters, I may be wrong. Here is another image where I change the draw order of "ship1", attention: "ship1" is way bellow my scene, if I do `ship1.draw();` first, the ship disappears (correct), but if I do `ship1.draw();` in last, he appears on top (incorrect).

[image]

**Video**: [Opengl Depth Problem video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ofM0x6GkGQc&feature=youtu.be)

- Q1) Does the draw order always matter?
- Q2) How do I fix this, should I change draw order every time I change camera position?

**Edit**: I also compared my class of Perspective Projection with the glm library, just to be sure that it´s not the problem with my projection Matrix. Everything is correct.

**Edit1**: I have my project on git: [Arkanoid git repository](https://github.com/RareFever/Arkanoid.git) (windows, project is ready to run at any computer with VS installed)

**Edit2**: I don´t use normals or texture. Just vertices and indices.

**Edit3**: Is there a problem, if every object on the scene uses(share) vertices from the same file ?

**Edit4**: I also changed my Perspective Projection values. I had near plane at 0.0f, now I have near=20.0f and far=500.0f, angle=60º. But nothing changes, view does but the depth not. =/

**Edit5**: Here is my Vertex and Fragment shaders.

**Edit6**: contact me any time, I am here all day, so ask me anything. At the moment I am rewriting all project from zero. I have two cubes which renders well, one in front of another. Already added mine class for: camera, projections, handler for shaders. Moving to Class which creates and draws objects.

```
// Vertex shader

in   vec4 in_Position;
    out vec4 color;
    uniform mat4 Model;
    uniform mat4 View;
    uniform mat4 Projection;

    void main(void)
    {
        color = in_Position;
        gl_Position =   Projection * View    * Model * in_Position;
    }

// Fragment shader

       #version 330 core
    in   vec4 color;
    out vec4 out_Color;
    void main(void)
    {
        out_Color = color;
    }
```

Some code:

```
 void setupOpenGL() {
    std::cerr << "CONTEXT: OpenGL v" << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;
    glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
    glDepthRange(0.0, 1.0);
    glClearDepth(1.0);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
}

    void display()
{
    ++FrameCount;
    glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    renderScene();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
void renderScene()
{
    wallNorth.draw(shader);
    obstacle1.draw(shader);
    wallEast.draw(shader);
    wallWest.draw(shader);
    ship1.draw(shader);
    plane.draw(shader);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a depth buffer? Depth test enabled?

Comment: Yes. Before every frame I do this:
`glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);`

Then, at the start of the program I run once these:
`glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
 glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
 glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
 glDepthRange(0.0, 1.0);
 glClearDepth(1.0);`

Comment: And you requested a depth buffer by including `GLUT_DEPTH` in the flags passed to `glutInitDisplayMode()`?

Comment: Yes. `glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);`.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is then. The most common problems to cause this are to either not have a depth buffer/test, or a projection matrix which has a depth range (ratio of *far* to *near*) that is way too large.

Comment: Thanks any way. By the way. My aspect ration is 1.33. 640x480. I use 60º FOV. =/
Actually, my project is in the git repository.
https://github.com/RareFever/Arkanoid.git

Comment: What are your near and far clipping planes?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I setup my projection with near=1.0f , far=100.f0f , fov=60º and aspect 1.33. I already tried different values, but nothing changes.

Comment: If you're using programmable vertex or fragment shaders, you might want to make sure they're handling depth values correctly.

Comment: @nneonneo Yes, I am using modern opengl and programmable shaders, I use only two: vertex and fragment shaders. How do I do that ? (handle the depth values correctly).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have cloned the repository you have linked to see if the issue was located somewhere else. In your most recent version the Object3D::draw function looks like this:

```
    glBindVertexArray(this->vaoID);

    glUseProgram(shader.getProgramID());
    glUniformMatrix4fv(this->currentshader.getUniformID_Model(), 1, GL_TRUE, this->currentMatrix.getMatrix());  // PPmat é matriz identidade
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 40, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (GLvoid*)0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glUseProgram(0);

    glClear( GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); <<< clears the current depth buffer.
```

The last line clears the depth buffer after each object that is drawn, meaning that the next object drawn is not occluded properly. You should only clear the depth buffer once every frame.

Comment: I would also suggest using `GL_LESS` for depth test instead of `GL_LEQUAL` as for latter draw order matters (when two objects have the same depth)

Comment: GL_LEQUAL could be useful when shading the same surface multiple times, for example decals or multiple pass lighting. But in this case it is probably a good idea to use GL_LESS.

Comment: @n0rd The draw order matters for both comparison functions if the depth is equal. It's just that for `GL_LESS`, the first one wins, and for `GL_LEQUAL` the last one wins.

Comment: Thank you ! What a simple mistake.

Comment: ok. I just came home, and can not run the program. Gives me this error: "0xc000007b". Which is weird as I tested the solution this morning, and everything was fine. So strange.

Comment: Where does this error happen, is it the result of glGetError() and which operation occurred before it?

Comment: @MauriceLaveaux it is not the result of glGetError(). I had working project uploaded to github. After your brilliant answer, I downloaded my project from github, deleted the glClear line, and it worked perfect this morning. After work, when I came home, Visual Studio gave me that error. And besides that, another of my projects also don't work. Very strange. I got mad, and created new project and added the files. Seems to work now. Some times I truly hate visual studio. In conclusion, everything works for now. =)